# sidewaystable doesn't resume numbering in list of table

Tags: tables, table-of-contents, rotating

I am using a `sidewaystable` for a table and is not resuming counting nor accepting the `H` attribute for floating.
What should i do for fixing it.

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: From what you've showed it seems that the figures are in multiple chapters and that you number your figures per chapter. Have you checked that?

Comment: @TeXnician it is about tables and yes are diffrent chapters

Comment: @dexteritas thank you so much in fact i am noob in latex and yes i am loading many packages i will follow these steps thanks so much :D

Comment: If those are in different chapters then you should also ask for that. Because probably its as easy as `\usepackage{chngcntr}\counterwithout{table}{chapter}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your picture shows a larger gap between the two entries what suggests multiple chapters. That means your documentclass or one of your packages resets the table numbering every chapter. To get rid of that just issue `\usepackage{chngcntr}\counterwithout{table}{chapter}` in your preamble.